# Can the display name (label) for one property change depending on the value of another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I have this viewmodel:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "End date")]
    public DateTime ProjectEnd { get; set; }
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    // more properties
}
```

I want the display name for `ProjectEnd` to change, depending on the value of `ProjectType`. `ProjectType` is not a user editable field, it is only set programmatically, in the controller.

I have tried this:

```
[Display(Name = (ProjectType == "project"?"End date":"Due date"))]
```

... but `ProjectType` throws this compile time error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ProjectViewModel.ProjectType'

Is what I'm trying possible? I could of course just hard code the label in the view, but I would like not to.

Another, slightly better solution could be to have two `DateTime`-properties, and depending on the value of `ProjectType`, just show one or the other in the view.

Comment: If you define the relationship between the field data and the label as part of the model data (to avoid coding this on the front end) then you could just display this in a hidden field on the page. You could then set a JavaScript event on the input data field, to check on changes and to refer to the hidden field to see what the label should be.

Comment: @Michael `ProjectType` doesn't change once the entity model has been created. It is set in the controller upon creation.

Comment: Cool, I like the look of @Nkosi's solution which defines the label as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is what I'm trying possible?

NO.

Possible Workaround

```
public class ProjectViewModel {    
    public string ProjectEndLabel => ProjectType == "project" ? "End date" : "Due date";
    public DateTime ProjectEnd { get; set; }
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    // more properties
}
```

And then in the view use a label HTML helper that binds to the `Model.ProjectEndLabel`

```html
@model ProjectViewModel

<!-- ... -->

<label for="ProjectEnd">@Model.ProjectEndLabel</label>
<input asp-for="ProjectEnd" /> <br />
```